# Why doesn't creating DIV element using JQuery work?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a div element with class and append a child it. But I am not getting any response. What might be the reason?

**JS content**

```
function createTable() {
var procDiv = $("<div class='proc-container'></div>");
var procUl = $("<ul></ul>")
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var li = $("<li></li>")
    li.innerText = "P" + i;
    procUl.appendChild(li);
}
procDiv.appendChild(procUl);

$(".container").get(0).appendChild(procDiv);
```

}

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="ga.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="createTable(1,1,1)">
<div class="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li` jQuery object does not have `.innerText` property; `procUL` jQuery object does not have `.appendChild()` method. Substitute using jQuery objects for `DOM` elements; `.text()` for `.innerText`,  `.append()` for `.appendChild()`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function createTable() {
    var procDiv = $("<div class='proc-container'></div>");
    var procUl = $("<ul></ul>")
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var li = $("<li></li>")
      li.text("P" + i);
      procUl.append(li);
    }
    procDiv.append(procUl);
    $(".container").append(procDiv);
  }
</script>

<body onload="createTable()">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Such simple beginner mistakes always exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your `proc` variables are being assigned jQuery objects. Consider using jQuery's `.append()` method.

```
$(".container").append(procDiv);
```

Comment: At first glance presumed that `li.innerText = "P" + i` would log an error at `console`, though appears to set the property at the jQuery `li` object, though not at `DOM` element `<li>` `.innerText` property